# DRF TypeError: create() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I am trying to save model with serializer, but getting TypeError on save method.
It seems the problem is not in data, or serializer, so I don't know how to solve it.

**serializers.py:**

```py
class DistributorSeializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Fields: exclude = ['company'].

    Overrides: `create()`, `to_representation()`.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Distributor
        exclude = ['company']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if request and hasattr(request, 'user'):
            worker: Type[Worker] = Worker.objects.get(user=request.user)
            validated_data['company'] = worker.company
            print(validated_data)
            print(self)
            return super().create(**validated_data)
            return self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

So when I am trying to call create method throw super class I am getting error, but when to do the same but throw Meta class - it works.

```
{'name': 'Name', 'address': 'Address', 'phone': '+48999999999', 'company': <Company: Smotors>}
DistributorSeializer(context={'request': <rest_framework.request.Request: POST '/companys/distributor/'>, 'format': None, 'view': <companys.views.DistributorsViewSet object>}, data={'name': 'Name', 'address': 'Address', 'phone': '+48999999999'}):
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=False, required=False)
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    address = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, max_length=255, required=False, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Distributor.objects.all())>])
    phone = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, max_length=16, required=False, validators=[<django.core.validators.RegexValidator object>])   
    comment = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, max_length=800, required=False)
    email = EmailField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, max_length=254, required=False)
    count = BooleanField(required=False)
Internal Server Error: /companys/distributor/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\march\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner    
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\march\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\march\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\march\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\march\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\march\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\march\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception        
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\march\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\march\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "C:\Users\march\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 24, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "C:\Users\march\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 205, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "D:\Stol\GitHub\smotors\companys\serializers.py", line 110, in create
    return super().create(**validated_data)
TypeError: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

So the name field is in the serializer fields, and validated_data has it.

Comment: `return super().create(validated_data)`

Comment: I don't play with django but are you sure you're to pass it as unpacked dict (**validated_data) and not just a dict like your own create got it? Usually with inheritance method signatures are kept fairly similar, and unpacking would mean changing number of arguments.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, it was the problem. Thank you very much

Comment: @h4z3 You are right, thank you

Comment: Remove the first `return`.